# Watch for changes in a text file, and handling when this file doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I've been making a project recently and I basically need to check for new text in a text file.
My code was this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.watch('./file.txt', (event, filename) => {
    fs.readFile('./file.txt', (err, data) => {
         if (err) throw err;
         data = JSON.parse(data);

         console.log(data);
    }
}
```

It worked great. However, sometimes, I must delete this file for whatever reasons, and thus my code crashes too!

Any idea on how to handle this? Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Node's built-in module `fs` doesn't support file deletion detection very well. There is a workaround using a package called [nsfw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nsfw) which is a wrapper around a native library that provides much better support for deletion detection.
The API is a bit odd but it is a solid package nonetheless.

Here is an example of what you're attempting to do using nsfw.

```js
const nsfw = require("nsfw");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const file = path.join(__dirname, "file.txt");
let watcher;
nsfw(
    file,
    ([event, ...restEvents]) => {
        switch (event.action) {
            case nsfw.actions.DELETED: {
                watcher.stop();
                return; // or handle this however you need to..
            }
            default: {
                fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) throw err;

                    try {
                        data = JSON.parse(data);

                        console.log(data);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error(error)
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
)
.then((w) => {
    watcher = w;
    watcher.start()
});
```